# Named and typesafe correlated subquery

Tags: java, jooq

I'm using JOOQ v3.14.3 and trying to do a simple select with a correlated subquery. In abstract ways:

```
Field<?> subquery = DSL.select(MY_TABLE.TIMESTAMP_FIELD)
        .from(MY_TABLE)
        .where(...)
        .asField("timestamp");

var mainQuery = create.select(OTHER_TABLE.SOME_FIELD, subquery)....;
```

My issue here is, that the subquery is guaranteed to return `OffsetDateTime` values, but in the resulting records I can only access those values using the plain String `"timestamp"` and have to do the manual casting like in

```
OffsetDateTime timestamp = (OffsetDateTime) record.get("timestamp");
```

One can create a type-safe `Field` like this:

```
Field<OffsetDateTime> subquery = DSL.field(DSL.select(MY_TABLE.TIMESTAMP_FIELD)
        .from(MY_TABLE)
        .where(...));
```

But this field doesn't seem to have a name so I can not easily retrieve it from the resulting Record. My subquery isn't constant so I have to recreate it everytime and can not simply keep a reference to this `Field`.

I'd imagine something like this: Define a custom named field, then use it in subquery and in Record access

```
public static final Field<OffsetDateTime> CUSTOM_TIMESTAMP_FIELD = Whatever.customField("timestamp", OffsetDateTime.class);

// ...

Field<OffsetDateTime> subquery = DSL.select(MY_TABLE.TIMESTAMP_FIELD)
        .from(MY_TABLE)
        .where(...)
        .asField(CUSTOM_TIMESTAMP_FIELD);

// ...

OffsetDateTime timestamp = record.get(CUSTOM_TIMESTAMP_FIELD);
```

What whould be the best/nicest way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Passing around the subquery reference

> But this field doesn't seem to have a name so I can not easily retrieve it from the resulting Record.

Have you tried it? Because you can just use the `subquery` reference to retrieve the value from the record:

```java
OffsetDateTime value = record.get(subquery)
```

Of course, you'd probably rather be aliasing your subquery like this:

```java
Field<OffsetDateTime> subquery = DSL.field(DSL.select(MY_TABLE.TIMESTAMP_FIELD)
        .from(MY_TABLE)
        .where(...))
        .as("subquery");
```

But then, you'd still use that reference to fetch the desired value.

#### Using a global variable for the subquery name

The approach you were looking for can be achieved like this:

```java
public static final Field<OffsetDateTime> CUSTOM_TIMESTAMP_FIELD = 
    DSL.field(DSL.name("timestamp"), OffsetDateTime.class);
```

You can now rename your subquery to it:

```java
Field<OffsetDateTime> subquery = DSL.field(DSL.select(MY_TABLE.TIMESTAMP_FIELD)
        .from(MY_TABLE)
        .where(...))
        .as(CUSTOM_TIMESTAMP_FIELD);
```

And then reuse that name in your record access:

```java
OffsetDateTime value = record.get(CUSTOM_TIMESTAMP_FIELD)
```

Comment: The subquery is built in a different place and not available at the (currently intended) place where I read from the record. That is why I can not just use the subquery reference. Also the subquery is dynamically generated from user input so I can not simply hold a static reference to it

Comment: These sound like arbitrary restrictions. With a more functional approach, you should be able to pass around the necessary references to whatever is needed to extract type safe information from the query where you construct it (see e.g. this blog post for some ideas: https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/16/a-functional-programming-approach-to-dynamic-sql-with-jooq/). I'll update my answer with another approach.

Comment: In your example, wouldn't I need to call the custom field 'subquery' in order to be able to look up its value from the resulting record? Otherwise I fail to see how this should work? Then I'd still have to keep the String literals in sync between query creation and reading from the result. I came up with this little example and I wonder what you do think about it? https://gist.github.com/skuzzle/8d3bbe8531fc1b742dd0d23d669b8cff

Comment: @SimonT: There's probably been a misunderstanding. I assumed you were going to use your dummy global field definition both in the alias specification and the record access. See my updated answer. Your linked gist approach is equivalent...

Comment: Now it makes sense. I somehow overlooked the `as(Field<?> other)` overload